# Get all possible values of a select field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select field with different values :

- africa
- europe
- america
- asia
- oceania

When selecting a value, I want to add a css class to a specific div, the name of the css class being the value selected. Easy enough :

```
  $(document).on("change",  "[data-name='continent'] select", function () {
    var continent = $('[data-name="continent"] select').val();
    $("#mydiv").addClass(continent);
  });
```

This works fine, but there is a problem : if I change the select field value, the previous classes will not be removed. I can't do :

```
$("#mydiv").removeClass().addClass(continent);
```

Because #mydiv already has other important classes.
I could do :

```
$("#mydiv").removeClass('africa').removeClass('europe').removeClass('america').removeClass('asia').removeClass('oceania').addClass(continent);
```

But in reality I have more than just 5 options and they might change in the future; I'd rather keep things flexible.
And more than anything, i want to learn javascript.
Is there any way to remove all the classes that are values of the select field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#continent').on('change', (e) => {
  let $myDiv = $('#myDiv'),
      $continent = $(e.target),
      possibleValues = $continent.find('option').toArray().map(item => item.value).join(' ');
  
  $myDiv.removeClass(possibleValues).addClass($continent.val());
});
```

Explanation:

1. Gather all possible values from the select:

   ```
   $continent.find('option').toArray().map(item => item.value)
   ```
2. Join them in a space-separated list into a string:

   ```
   .join(' ');
   ```
3. Remove all classes from that list from the target element

   ```
   $myDiv.removeClass(possibleValues)
   ```
4. Add the selected class after it.

Demo:

```js
$('#continent').on('change', (e) => {
  let $myDiv = $('#myDiv'),
      $continent = $(e.target),
      possibleValues = $continent.find('option').toArray().map(item => item.value).join(' ');
  
  $myDiv.removeClass(possibleValues).addClass($continent.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="continent">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
  <option value="d">D</option>
  <option value="e">E</option>
</select>

<div id="myDiv" class="other-class keep-me">my div</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and thank you even more for the explanation. This is how i learn!

Comment: Hi, I just implemented your solution successfully, thank you again. 
Now I would like to make it work also on open. Since I don't know how to make a function work both "on change" and "on open", i duplicated your code and adapted it. I tried different things but no luck. I believe it's the e.target that I don't know how to use. Here is my last attempt : 

  `let $myDiv = $('#myDiv'),
      $continent = $('#continent').target,
      possibleValues = $continent.find('option').toArray().map(item => item.value).join(' ');
  $myDiv.removeClass(possibleValues).addClass($continent.val());`

Comment: @Kev What you mean by "on open", on page load ? If yes, you can try using `document.ready`, like: `$(document).ready(() => { $('#continent').change(); });`

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of the classes you want to remove, you can use something like this:

```
[...testEl.querySelectorAll('option')].map(x => x.value).join(' ');
```

This is vanilla JavaScript...if done in jQuery it would look like this:

```
$('#my-select > option').map((i,el)=> el.value).toArray().join(' ');
```

That will pull out a list of the options and give you a space-delimited string. You could then use this list to do your `.removeClass()`.

However I wonder if class is the best option for this. In the following snippet there is an example of using a data attribute instead of class, and how that data attribute could be used in a CSS selector (this would also work in `jQuery` or `querySelector`). Maybe an option to consider...

```js
const testEl = document.querySelector('#test');

const allOptions = $('#test > option').map((i,el)=> el.value).toArray().join(' ');
console.log(allOptions);

const testChange = e => {
  const el = e.target;
  el.dataset.chosen = el.value;
};
testEl.addEventListener('change', testChange);
testChange({ target: testEl });
```

```css
#test[data-chosen="africa"] {
  color: red;
}

#test[data-chosen="america"] {
  color: blue;
}

#test {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='test' id='test' value='europe'>
  <option value='africa'>africa</option>
  <option value='europe'>europe</option>
  <option value='america'>america</option>
  <option value='asia'>asia</option>
  <option value='oceania'>oceania</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed i thought about an attribute instead of a class but this was beyond my skills. I'll try the standard way with classes then I'll try to the second one to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a string containing all the classes you want to add/remove seperated by space:

```
$("#mydiv").removeClass("africa europe america asia oceania");
```